# referenceError: Can't find variable: BigInt when using @solana/web3.js on React in Safari

Tags: web3.js

I have a react app built with @solana/web3.js .It works fine on google chrome but doesnt work on Safari. I guess its because BigInt doesnt work fine with Safari. Please who can suggest a polyfill to help with it?

Comment: What version of Safari are you having trouble with? Bigint compatibility was introduced in Safari on September 15 2020.